# How to convert two digit number to single digit in C#

Tags: c#

How to make two or three digits number to single digit, example: 12= 1+2= single digit is 3 or 95=9+5=14=1+4= single digit 5 in C#

Comment: Seems like homework. Can you show what did you tried and where your exact problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework

Comment: @Manu it's not the actual answer :)

Comment: Voting to close because its homework isn't a valid reason.

Answer (score 2):

Homework or not, here's one way to do it.

```
int number = 95;
// or while (number >= 10)
while (number.ToString().Length > 1) // Do while we got a number that's 10 or more.
{
    number = number.ToString() // Converts to string.
       .ToCharArray() // Splits it into an array of characters. (eg. one digit)
       .Select(x => (int)char.GetNumericValue(x)) // Converts that character into an int.
       .Sum(); // Calculate the sum.
}
```

Number will have the value of `5`.

Comment: and what if number=95?

Comment: It will be 14. Shouldn't it be?

Comment: 95 = 9+5 = 14 = 1+4 = single digit 5

Comment: @AntonioPelleriti - Thank you. I've updated.

Comment: On a different note... while calculating unit number; the answer is same as number if other number is "9". So, @Khan, you can ignore 9 and print other number :-) Jokes apart... I hope you have too many solutions now...

Comment: another solution, if you like recursion :) :


`public static int SumDigits(int n)
{
 int sum = n.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(x => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(x)).Sum();
 return sum > 9 ? SumDigits(sum): sum;
}`

Comment: to get single digit lucky number using the following scenario;

  e.g. replace ‘a’ with 1, ‘b’ with 2 and ‘c’ with 3.

* Add all numbers until it becomes a single digit e.g.

For name cow = 3+15+23

= 41

= 4+1

= 5

Answer (score 2):

a recursive solution:

```
public static int SumDigits(int n) 
{ 
  int sum = n.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(x => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(x)).Sum(); 
  return sum > 9 ? SumDigits(sum): sum; 
}
```

enhancement to [smoksnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4949005/smoksnes) answer!

Answer (score 1):

May be this would solve your problem.

```
int num = 12;
int sum = num;
int rem = 0;
bool isitFirstTime = true;
if (sum > 9)
{
    if(!isitFirstTime)
    {
        num = sum;
    }
    else
    {
        sum = 0;
    }
    while (num != 0)
    {
        rem = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        sum = sum + rem;
    }
    isitFirstTime = false;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution (convertion char to string before gettting it's in value is weird and should not be used in prodution), but i am sure it works)

```
public static int StringToNumber(string text)
{
   int value = 0;
   foreach(char c in text)
   {
     int temp;
     if (!int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out temp)) throw new InvalidArgumentException(nameof(text));
     value += temp;
     if (value > 9) value = value / 10 + value % 10;
   }
   return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works...

```
private static string CalculateUnitNumber(string sInput)
    {
        char[] array = sInput.ToCharArray();
        List<int> sequence = array.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString())).ToArray().ToList();
        string sSum = sequence.Sum() + "";
        while (sSum.Length != 1)
        {
            sSum = CalculateUnitNumber(sSum);
        }
        return sSum;
    }
```

You can pass 2,3,4... digit numbers as input...

Comment: `CalculateUnitNumber("not a number")` will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

[Recursion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3dk2cc3(v=vs.100).aspx) is very handy in cases like this.
Take a look at this:

```
int SumOfDigits(int source)
{
    if (source < 100)
    {
        int temp = source / 10;
        int sum = (source - (temp * 10)) + temp ;
        if (sum < 10) return sum;
        else return SumOfDigits(sum);
    }
    else throw new System.InvalidOperationException("source number can not be bigger than 99");
}
```

When you use it:

```
var result = SumOfDigits(47); //will be 2
```

Comment: What will be result of `SumOfDigits(-1)` ? I think it's not universal

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer. without recursion and LINQ.

```
private static int SumOfDigits(int value)
{
   int result = 0;
   while (value > 0) 
   {
      result += value % 10;
      value /= 10;
   }
   return result; 
}

public static int StringToDigit(string text)
{
   int value = 0;
   if (!int.TryParse(text, out value)) throw new InvalidArgumentException(nameof(text));
   if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(text));
   while (value >= 10) value = SumOfDigits(value);  
   return value;
}
```